# C# .NET poor sorted containers

Tags: c#, containers, sorting

I'm to write an event based simulator in C#. I need a sorted container for the scheduler that has the following capabilities:

- Key - Value pairs are stored sorted by the key (Time, Delegate pairs)
- Efficient inserts and removes by key (Smallest items are removed, inserts are arbitrary)
- The smallest item (key value pair) can be queried.

What I need is actually a very basic binary tree or a sorted queue or something similar. But the options I have in .NET - SortedList and SortedDictionary - are unsatisfactory. The first has efficiency issues with inserts and removes, the second has problems with querying the smallest items.

Should I start implementing my own container or I miss something? It is so unbelievable that there is no built in container that fits my needs.

Thanks!

(update: Im looking for a solution under .NET 2.0)

Comment: Use a `SortedDictionary` and keep track of the smallest item yourself?

Comment: @Tim Robinson - Sounds like an answer?!?

Comment: What's wrong with `sortedDictionary.First()`?

Comment: @Pieter I thought this was obvious, so I might be missing the point

Comment: @Tim Robinson - More often than not, a simple solution is what the OP is looking for. Can always give it a shot. +1 for you.

Comment: Sorry. I've forgotten to mention that I use .Net 2.0 where First() is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could still use a `SortedDictionary` if you kept track of the smallest item yourself.

But I have the same question as @Frédéric - what's wrong with `sortedDictionary.First()`?

**Edit:** As per Frédéric's suggestion, an `Enumerable.First` implementation for .NET 2.0:

```
public static T First(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    foreach (T item in items)
        return item;

    throw new InvalidOperationException("The source sequence is empty.");
}
```

Comment: This is not practicaly possible, since the smallest items are removed from the container. So after removing it, I have to get the smallest value again...

Comment: I really think the answer is `First` - see my edit. (Even if Microsoft add functionality in new versions of the framework, you're still allowed to re-implement it for older versions.)

Comment: Yes, you are right! I would have never thought about reimplementing this simple function :) Thanks for your and all the others' invaluable answers!

Comment: (Just a remark. I cannot understand why MS could not add some more flexible sorted containers. There are really basic functionalities that has not been implemented. For instance duplicate keys in sorted containers. Ok, I stop crying :) )

Answer (score 0):

If the .NET collections don't provide the functionality and performance that you're looking for, you might want to consider the [C5 library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it.